# Feeling dizzy with Metal Gear Solid V

Tags: health, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I started playing the game, and I had to stop multiple times, because I was feeling very dizzy.

I looked at the configuration menu, and disabled the camera shake, but it's still enduring.

Is there a way to disable it completely?

Comment: Isn't this where you stop playing and call a doctor?

Comment: I agree with @Ender. When you start feeling dizzy while playing games, and it's not a passing thing, you should see a doctor to understand *why* you're feeling dizzy. You think it's because of the shaking, but it might be caused by something else entirely: lights flashing, field of view, blur, etc. Or it might be something worse... Best see a doctor.

Comment: I'm unclear if you're saying after changing the setting you're still getting dizzy but the camera shaking stopped, or that trying to disable the camera shake didn't seem to actually disable the camera shake.

Comment: This only happens to me when a game uses the camera shake. For example: Dead Island, Stalker or MGS5.

Comment: The camera shake stills after I disable it on the configuration menu.

Comment: If the camera shake stills after you disable it, does that fix the problem?

Comment: No. Disabling the option reduces part of the camera shake but on every cinematic there is a lot of camera shake.

Comment: It makes sense that the option only affects gameplay as this is the equivalent to things like head bobbing. Some people like it some people don't. There is no logical reason for the option disable this in cinematics. Its like unticking a box to take the action scenes out of a film. As others have said the most important course of action is to find out what is causing your symptoms and go from there. It sounds stupid but have you tried windowing the game when a cinematic is playing and watching it in a small window. Does this make any difference?

Comment: I suffer from motion sickness which is triggered in some games (Dead Island is one that clearly sticks in my head). For me it was to do with the field of view and the amount of motion blur during the game's tutorial. I turned off the motion blur but unfortunately there was no option to alter the field of view. After the main game started however I was fine.

Comment: Field of view is probably the culprit. I can't say anything for certain but FOV is often the cause of dizziness and motion sickness when playing games (MW3's 65 FOV caused players a whole host of problems). Try an FOV mod/fix to widen the FOV and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it at 720p. For some reason that helped me

Comment: And how exactly would this be able to help?

Comment: @Texenox Because of black magic i guess

Comment: This might actually help.  By reducing the detail of the game, it should be less objects on screen and generally larger display of everything else.  For some people, it's not just moment but tracking of small objects that affect their senses.

Comment: Could help framerate issues as well. Lots of AAA games use tricks like scaling or different frame rates to crank up visual detail. It is possible the OP is affected by an imperceptible flicker.